# FormatException error when using string.Format

Tags: c#, console

Every time I try and input the number of sales. Input string was not in a correct format when running this method.

```
int numberOfSales = 0;
double[] sales;
Console.Write("Please enter number of sales: ");
numberOfSales = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
sales = new double[numberOfSales];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSales; i++)
{

   Console.Write("Please enter  sales #{0}:", i + 1);

   sales[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}

double sum = sales.Sum();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSales; i++)
{

   double contrubution = sales[i] / sum;

   Console.WriteLine("Sale # {0} was {1:C2} and contributed {2P:P2}", i + 1, sales[i], contrubution);
}

Console.WriteLine("Total sum of sales is {0:C2}", sum);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with (and may not be limited to) `2P`.

**The Background**

The braces in a `string.Format` denotes a *Format Item*. They are represented by a Token *Number* followed by and optional `:` and a [Format Specifier](http://Formatting%20Types%20in%20.NET).

Token *Number* `{0}` is the *Index* of the object whose string value will be inserted at that position.

**The Solve**

As you can see in your code you have `{2P:P2}` which doesn't start with a format *Item Number*. It should be `{2:P2}`

```
Console.WriteLine("Sale # {0} was {1:C2} and contributed {2:P2}", i + 1, sales[i], contrubution);
```

**Additional**

May i suggest [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) which was introduced in `C#6` instead, its easier to read, and less likely you'll make a mistake like this

```
Console.WriteLine($"Sale # {(i + 1)} was {sales[i]:C2} and contributed {contrubution:P2}");
```